# Dizi poem on my dizi flute please

Tags: poetry

Could someone please translate the text carved on my dizi? Please, thank you, with all my heart
[image]

Comment: `不知何處吹蘆管, 一夜征人盡望鄕`.

Comment: Translation questions are off-topic for this site (as they generally are on language sites across SE) unless prior research has been shown.

Answer (score 2):

夜上受降城闻笛

Hearing the Flute at Night on Shouxiang Walls

朝代：唐代

748-827 AD, Tang Dynasty

作者：李益

Li Yi, China
                                                                                               Translator: Ying Sun © 2008

原文：

> 回乐峰前沙似雪，The sand below Huile Peak is as white as snow.
>
> 受降城外月如霜。Outside Shouxiang Walls frost-like moonbeams glow.
>
> **不知何处吹芦管，**  Someone is playing the flute - not sure from where.
>
> **一夜征人尽望乡。**  Over night all soldiers get homesickness hard to bear.do Homeward night levy .

source:http://www.musicated.com/syh/tangpoems.htm#LiYi01